# Django HardCoding Many to Many fields in a form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, hardcode

I am trying to hardcode the following in my view for testing purposes. How do I do this without encountering an error?

My view:

`def create(request):
    form= PlayForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():

```
    play = form.save(commit=False)
    play.track = 2
    play.save()
    request.user.message_set.create(message='Play Was created')
    if 'next' in request.POST:
        next = request.POST['next']
    else:
        next = reverse('coup_show')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
return render_to_response(
    'dash/create.html',
    {'form':form},
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)`
```

My model:

```
class Play(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track,null=True, related_name='track_creator_set')
```

When I try this I get the following error...

```
Cannot assign "2": "Play.track" must be a "Track" instance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
play.track = Track.objects.get(pk=2)
```

You need to assign an instance of the Track model, rather than just the pk.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to set it to track 2?

How about:

```
play.track = Track.objects.get(id=2)
```

The error is telling you that you're trying to give it a number, when in fact you need a Track, so the solution is to give it a Track. :)